# How to display data with in a table format

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to search the data from mysql and need to display it in a table. Here searching of data is successful but the data is not getting displayed in table, instead it is displaying in a straight line. Here am using $output method. My codings are

### form.php

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Seacrh By Name</h1>
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <label>Name:
  <input type="text" name="keyname" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### search.php

```
<?php

//capture search term and remove spaces at its both ends if the is any
$searchTerm = trim($_GET['keyname']);

//check whether the name parsed is empty
if($searchTerm == "")
{
echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
exit();
}

//database connection info
$host = "xx"; //server
$db = "xx"; //database name
$user = "xx"; //dabases user name
$pwd = "xx"; //password

 //connecting to server and creating link to database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

//MYSQL search statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE id LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* check whethere there were matching records in the table
by counting the number of results returned */
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
{
    $output = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{


$output .= "id: " . $row['id'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "name: " . $row['name'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "Telephone: " . $row['Telephone'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "E_mail: " . $row['E_mail'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "visa_category: " . $row['visa_category'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "other_category: " . $row['other_category'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "passport_no: " . $row['passport_no'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$output .= "remarks: " . $row['remarks'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

}
echo $output;
}
else
    echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;
?>
```

How can i display my data's in html table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$output` is only outputting the data itself. Make it also output an [HTML table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

```
echo '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
        </tr>';

}

echo '
</table>';
```

By the way, **don't scroll down straight to the code**, see the warnings about when/how to use tables as well.

Comment: U r Experienced but i am not

Comment: That's why you need to try learning, not copy/paste solely what other people create. You can use their help to understand how to do something, but you'll never learn how to code if you don't understand how it works. Also use proper English, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include("include/connect.php");
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM `employee` ";
//echo $sqlStr . "<br>";
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


echo '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>date of joining</th>
        <th>date of living in service</th>
        <th>salary</th>
    </tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['emp_id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['DOJ'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['DLS'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['salary'].'</td>
        </tr>';

}

echo '
</table>';
?>
```